# productConnected(_ product: DJIBaseProduct?) delegate not called

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to connect `Mavic Air` using `DJISDK.framework`. After I call

```
DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()
```

the following delegate method is not called:

```
productConnected(_ product: DJIBaseProduct?)
```

I am using the following versions:

```
DJI-SDK-iOS 4.8.1
iOS version 11.4.1
XCode version 10.0
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your questions is missing some details which may by useful for community to help you. Please read the following article about asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You likely still need to register the app with the framework. you should register the app before calling `startConnectionToProduct()`.

**This link should be very helpful:**
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding these keys in plist

UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols(array) - com.dji.video, com.dji.protocol, com.dji.common